# WebRTC merge video MediaStreamTracks into one on client side

Tags: javascript, webrtc

How i can merge 2 video streams into one on client side, and send it through WebRTC PeerConnection?

For example i have 2 video streams like this

```
navigator.getUserMedia({ video: true }, successCamera, error);  //  capture camera

function successCamera(streamCamera) {
    vtCamera = streamCamera.getVideoTracks()[0]

    navigator.getUserMedia({  //  capture screen
        video: {   
            mandatory: {
                chromeMediaSource: 'screen',
                maxWidth: 1280,
                maxHeight: 720
            }
        }
    }, successScreen, error);

    function successScreen(streamScreen) {
        vtScreen = streamScreen.getVideoTracks()[0]

        mergedVideoTracks = vtScreen + vtCamera;   //  How i can merge tracks in one??

        finallyStream = streamScreen.clone()
        finallyStream.removeTrack( finallyStream.getVideoTracks()[0] )
        finallyStream.addTrack( mergedVideoTracks )

        finallyStream  // I need to send this through WebRTC PeerConnection

    }

}

function error(error) {
    console.error(error);
}
```

As you can see i have vtScreen and vtCamera as MediaStreamTracks. I need to set screen as background, and camera as small frame in right bottom corner. And send it through WebRTC PeerConnection as one stream

Yes, i can merge it on canvas, but i don't know how i can send this canvas as MediaStreamTrack. =(

Comment: You could simply make two different media streams and add both to the peerconnection and handle the negotiation.

Comment: @BenjaminTrent Yes, i can add 2 streams and merge it on another PC. But i have to write vod file on server side. When i tried to merge different streams on server side, i had a problems. I don't know how need to (merge streams, manage scene, add/remove video/audio tracks) without stop/start stream.

Comment: Maybe I need clarification on what you mean by merge...

Comment: @BenjaminTrent For example i have one MediaStreamTrack with screen share on fullscreen and small window with camera at the right bottom corner

Comment: @BenjaminTrent, in my case I have two video streaming-like video calls. One is a local user and the other is a remote user, I want to record both video streaming. So how can I merge/combine those two video streaming so I can record it?